# Can I use wifi direct to find position of a device

Tags: wifi-direct

If i had 2+ devices connected to a wifi direct access point would it technically be possible in theory to ascertain the devices physical position in relation to each other?

Thanks

Comment: Since every device communicate with the access point, no. You need to do triangulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it is possible to get an estimate of their directions to each other when using multiple receive antennas.

Modern notebooks and access points often have multiple antennas for MIMO communication, which increases the reliability and/or the bandwidth. Devices like these could be used for what is called Direction-of-Arrival estimation.

This is a non-trivial topic and doesn't really belong in Stackoverlow but for a mathematical introduction you could look [at this paper](http://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~rsadve/Notes/DOA.pdf)

Comment: To add on this - the idea stems out of triangulation principle

Comment: @icepack Yes, the simplest forms of DoA estimation use a similar principle. But it gets far more complex than that for the more reliable methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see how; location determined via wifi is based on the location of the access point.

Comment: thks so could you see where the device was in relation to the wireless access point?

Answer (score 0):

not really. You could connect over bluetooth to calculate this. But it's not really reliable. Because you have only the signal strenght for calculating the difference between two devices.

Comment: Signal strength can give only the distance, that's not enough to determine location. And how is BT related to this?